# fb_graph rails: how to store all friends to mongoid? why is it so slow by using each/map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, fb-graph

```
@fb_friends = @fb_user.friends
@fb_friends.each do |friend|
  friend_profile = friend.fetch
  puts friend_profile.name
end
```

with above codes,i was able to retrieve all the friends' name but they are running super slow.
Took more than 10mins to retrieve all the friends.

So I was wondering whats the problem? Instead of using iteration to loop over the friends, can i store them directly by converting @fb_friends to json and store them to mongoid?

Thanks

Comment: What are your models, and what are the typical DB queries in the log file for friend.fetch?